# change and onchange don't work on my computer. what might be causing this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code should pop up an alert box whenever I select a file or make a change to the textbox and click out of it.

I believe the code SHOULD work, but it doesn't. Isolating the code snippets on JSFiddle and running them even works.

Is anything wrong with my code? If not, could something on my computer be preventing this code from working?

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("file").onchange(function() {
           alert($(this).val()); 
        });

        $('#text').change(function() {
           alert($(this).val()); 
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
    <input id="text" type="text" name="text" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 3rror404's answer was correct. However, I have an additional error in my code. The correct code is "document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {...};" Thus, the script stopped before it ran the jQuery even when I included the code in the "document.ready".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your function in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

jsfiddle does this for you (I think)

Alternatively use:

```
$(window).ready(function() {

});
```

if you want to ensure that the entire page has loaded before trying to run your code.

Further reading:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: It does; if you look at the left hand panel there's a `select` (abov the library `select`) with `option`s for `no wrap (head)`, `no wrap (body)`, `onLoad` and `onDomReady`.

Comment: Could somebody please format the above link for me? I can't do it on my phone. Thanks

Comment: This didn't help. Edited post to include new code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, Is jquery actually loading when you run the local page?